# Is stdout/stderror not part of the promise fulfillment from the ssh-promise library?

Tags: javascript, ssh, promise, q

I have the following code which promisifies a number of functionCalls to various servers. On the return of all the functionCalls the response object is sent to the Mongo database and stored as a single document.  The reason for the promises is that all of the functions must complete and their return value be in the response section so that the database can store all of the appropriate responses. (code follows)

```
 Q.all(functionCalls)
     .then(function(response) {
        //console.log(response);
        Q.then(dbHandler(response))
           .catch( function(e) {
              console.log(e);
           })
           .finally( function() {
              console.log('Execution completed successfully!');
           });
     }, function() {
        console.log('unhandled exception');
     });
```

The problem I am experiencing is with a single function call that involves the ssh-promise library. The issue is that the promise is resolved before the stdout or stderror fields are populated in the response.  Here is the code for the ssh call. Snipped code for brevity follows:

```
   var ssh = new Client(config);
   var ack = "200 - OK";
   var pub = {};

   var execString = "java -classpath" + classpath + javaSecurityArgs + " -DAPP_ENV=" + env + javaMainClass + jobString + " date=" + seconds;
   ssh.exec( execString )
      .then( function(stdout) {
         json.parse(stdout.match(/^FulfillmentReportJson:(.*)$/gm))
            .catch(function (e) {
               console.log(e.message);
               pub = {
                  'type': 'fulfillmentBatch',
                  'result': 'failed'
               };
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                  console.log(stdout);
                  pub = {
                     'type': 'fulfillmentBatch',
                     'result': response
                  };
               }
            )
      })
      .catch(function(stderr) {
         pub = {
            'type': 'fulfillmentBatch',
            'result': 'failed' + stderr
         };
      })
      .done();
```

The promise fulfillment of "then" returns the response from either stdout or stderror and populates it in the pub.result which is returned.

**The question is this:** When I execute this code the promise finishes before the stdout or stderror is returned by the ssh.exec. It is like the promise fulfills, then nearly 5 seconds later (well after the database object has been written) we see the return of the stdout/stderror data.  The database object contains a 'null' from the spot where this function should have populated data and the console.log(stdout) in the 'then' section contains the stdout/stderror data.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Snipped code for brevity` - the code you posted doesn't exactly match the description that `The promise fulfillment of "then" returns the response from either stdout or stderror` ... also, any error in `json.parse` (not JSON.parse I gather, as that doesn't return a promise) will be handled by the .catch, and then the "inner" then that follows will overwrite the `pub` ... and that's just the obvious issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed the code after the response above realizing I was approaching the ssh command incorrectly.

```
  ssh.exec(execString, {
  exit: function(code, stdout, stderr) {
```

I should have been using the 'exit' instead of 'out' and 'err' responses on the exec. The exit allows the building of the appropriate response object